# How to push a dockerized project on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, heroku, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

hope you are fine!

Actually, I have a dockerized rails API I'm working on.& I have to push it on Heroku.

I add pg gem to my production environment & move MySql gem to the development environment

```html
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a   console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'mocha'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'mysql2'
  
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '1.2.3'
end
```

And after that, I run `docker-compose up --build` & after pushing my code to git I run `git push heroku <branch name>` everything works fine.
but when I run `heroku run rails db:migrate` i got an error

> rails aborted! NoMethodError: Cannot load database configuration:
> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

This is my first time to push a dockerized project on Heroku, I don't know how to do this.
can anyone please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

When deploying a Docker container Heroku you need to follow a different method (currently you are just pushing the code `git push heroku master`).

First step: build your Docker image locally and test it.

```
# build image
docker build -t com.example/myapp .
# run container using mapping port 8886 to 8886
docker run -it --name myapp -p 8886:8886 com.example/myapp
```

Second step: login into Heroku registry (only needed once)

```
heroku container:login
```

Third step: tag and push

```
# tag to match Heroku naming template (this is example uses `web` Dyno)
docker tag com.example/myapp registry.heroku.com/myapp/web
docker push registry.heroku.com/myapp/web
```

Final step: release (aka start the application)

```
heroku container:release web -a myapp
```

See full reference at [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime)

Comment: ok i try this but im not pushing my master branch on heroku but another branch does it right

Comment: You build the Docker image with the branch you want (on your local dev environment) then you push the image. Heroku registry is not aware of which branch/code you wan to run, just the image that you will push

Comment: it  is the name of the image, you can just call it `myapp` or use a prefix/domain `com.google/myapp`