# Heroku Slug Size Too Large due to Keras

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, heroku, keras

I'm deploying my app to heroku however their free tier only allow < 500MB packages, I'm currently using tensorflow and it takes > 500 MB, I can downgrade it to lower version or use the tensorflow-cpu instead, however, I'm also using Keras, which requires at least tensorflow=2.2.0 (so size > 500MB).

I have looked into these two questions but somehow downgrading Keras causes a lot of imcompatible issues.

[Deploy python app to Heroku "Slug Size too large"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61062303/deploy-python-app-to-heroku-slug-size-too-large)

[Error "Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465620/error-keras-requires-tensorflow-2-2-or-higher)

What I want to achieve is to be able to use Keras while the size of my packages < 500MB so that I can push my app to heroku

Comment: You can try [docker based deployment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime). This takes some amount of work to setup but you won't be restricted by the slug size.

Comment: I don't see how tensorflow version implies >500 MB. You control size of the model. You can prune it or use reduced precision for starters. Have you considered that?

Comment: I don't think he's talking about the model. He is talking about the tensorflow package. The package doesn't meet the size limits of the deployment environment.

Comment: I'm not familiar with docker, is there a step by step procedure that I can follow to deploy my app? @SumitChaturvedi

Comment: Docker on Heroku: see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64817761/9095551

Comment: Were you able to solve it. If not I can post an answer describing my experience in deploying an app which required pytorch.